# C program to read a file and print just the numbers

Tags: c

I have a file containing strings as well as numbers. Eg. my file Store-1.txt contains "coffee 2mug -4".
I need a c program to store the numbers only (i.e 2 and -4) by reading a file and saving just the numbers into an array.

i am not able to figure out how exactly to do this. Any suggestions please.

code is

```
#include <stdio.h>


int main(void)
 {
 char c,ch;
 int flag=0;
  FILE *fptr=fopen("Store-1.txt","r");
  if(fptr)
 {
 while((c=fgetc(fptr))!=EOF)
 {
 if(c=='-' || c== '+')
     {
      ch=c;
      flag=1;
     }
 if(c>='0' && c<='9')
  {
    if(flag == 1)
     { 
       printf("%c",ch); flag =0;
      }
   printf("%c",c);
  }
   }
   }
  else
printf("Error : file not found");

  system("pause");
 }
```

Comment: do you need my code.? let me know so that i can upload it.

Comment: Just put it into your question.

Comment: @user1805494, yes, we need your code...

Comment: @user1805494 : `fclose(fptr);`  in the last.. I added it to my recent edit see my answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

read a file using `fgetc()` and `printf()` it if

`c>='0' && c<='9'`

Here is the full working code :

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
char c,ch;
int flag=0;
FILE *fp=fopen("file.txt","r");
if(fp)
{
    while((c=fgetc(fp))!=EOF)
    {
     if(c=='-' || c== '+')
         {
          ch=c;
          flag=1;
          continue;
         }
     if(c>='0' && c<='9')
      {
        if(flag == 1)
         {
           printf("%c",ch); flag =0;
          }
       printf("%c",c);
      }
     else
        flag=0;
    }
}
else
    printf("Error : file not found");

fclose(fp);}
```

Comment: doesn't take care of negative numbers. store last number read and decide on the sign if it is the character `-`.

Comment: yeah sure : but OP wants the basic concept in this . So I haven't taken care of all possible test cases

Comment: his example is "coffee 2mug -4" and he wants -4.

Comment: I thought it just the - sign in string and he actually want only digits or numbers

Comment: @user1805494: It is working ..you can check it and accept it if you agree

Comment: @user1805494: It's running on my compiler

Comment: my file is saved on my desktop as " Store-1" . I have written your code by modifying fopen("Store-1","r")

Also i am using the command system("pause") since Dev C++ doesnt seem to show the console screen when i do not use it.

Comment: give full path like "/root/desk/../../Strore-1" and also see my new answer and copy and run it

Comment: It must run  copy paste my this answer and try. If agree accept the answer

Comment: yes..it works. Could you please modify it a bit to store the numbers in an array.

Comment: You can do it man just think ... programming is not like just asking the answer from ohter.You can only learn by doing and thinking by self

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
   int ch, n, sign;

   sign = 1;
   ch = getchar();
   while (ch != EOF) {
      if (ch == '-') {
         sign = -1;
         ch = getchar();
      } else if (isdigit(ch)) {
         n = 0;
         do {
            n = n * 10 + ch - '0';
            ch = getchar();
         } while (isdigit(ch));
         n *= sign;
         /*store n*/
      } else {
         sign = 1;
         ch = getchar();
      }
   }
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: That will incorrectly consume a negative sign that followed a digit. (Like "2-3"). Although it's unclear what would the OP want to happen in this case.